# Scaling Bezier curve first and second derivative?

Tags: derivatives, bezier-curve

I'm trying to use a cubic Bezier curve for ease-in-ease-out movement in 1 dimension. The output is position, first derivative is velocity, and second derivative is acceleration to control a motor. But a Bezier curve is defined in terms of 0-1 and I might need to move 1.9 meters. For position, I can multiply (e.g. by 1.9) to scale, but is there a way to scale the first and second derivatives?

Comment: Are you aware that for the parameterization $t \in [0,1]$, the value of $t$ is different from the "curvilinear abscissa" (for example, when $t=1/2$, you are (in general) not exactly halfway from the endpoints) ?

Comment: I wasn't aware of curvilinear abscissa specifically, but I knew when at t = 1/2, I couldn't just use y because it may be at a different x so I had to find x at t (using roots) then find the y at that x. But I'll learn about curvilinear abscissa.

Comment: Where do yo intend to place your $1.9$ ? Is it by taking the parameterization $t/1.9$ instead of $t$ for example by taking $x=t/1.9, y=a(t/1.9)^3+b(t/1.9)^2+c(t/1.9)+d$.  then recompute the derivative $x'(t),y'(t)$ and the acceleration $x''(t),y''(t)$ with these new expressions.

Comment: I'm not sure where to place the 1.9. For position, I was using t/1.9 on input to normalize to [0,1] then scaling with y*1.9 on output (allowing me to use the Bezier derivations from Wikipedia). But for velocity and acceleration, it's not linear so I wasn't sure how to scale them.

Comment: it is why I advise you to use $x=t/1.9, y=a(t/1.9)^3+b(t/1.9)^2+c(t/1.9)+d$, from which the velocity vector has components $(x'(t)=1/1.9, y'(t)=3a(t^2)/(1.9^3)+2bt/(1.9)^2+c/1.9)$ i.e. replace the previous velocity vector by this one. Similar operation for the acceleration vector.

Comment: It looks like scaling the y component of the control points of the Bezier curve causes the output y component to be scaled. For example, if divide P0-P4's y by 1.9, the resulting graph is vertically squished by 1.9.